# how to increase the width of an element without using any loops

Tags: javascript, width

when ever we think to increase the width if an element or height we always think that... okey for loop will be some part of that code... because you know we have to again and again go on increasing the value of width property.

there are vague codes in our mind like this:

```
var somefunction = function(elementName,width){

 var var1 = docuemnt.getElementById(elementName), //some more variable

 /*

   maybe complicated or simple codes

 */ 

  for( var i = var1.clientWidth; i<=....., i++ ){

   // some code in this loop

  }  
}
```

and you know when i searched on how to increase the width of an element then all the answer codes had `for` loop

but now i want that is there other way around to this function without using any loop?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do this is by using `setInterval` the following code does that:

it only uses `setInterval`. you know it go on repeating itself after every set Interval.

```js
function c (e,s,v){
 var ele = document.getElementById(e),
 width= ele.clientWidth;

 var incInWidthOfEle = setInterval(function(){

   if (width <= s) {
     increase();
    }else{
     stop_();
    };

   }, v);   

 var increase = function(){

   ele.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + width +'px;');
   width++ ;
 };

 var stop_ = function(){

  clearInterval(incInWidthOfEle);

 };

};
c('d1', 500, 10);
```

```css
#d1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
 }
```

```html
<body>

<div id="d1" style="width:200px;"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a code snippet using javascript and `transition`

```js
window.onload = function(){
    setWidth(500);
}

function setWidth(width) {
  var1 = document.getElementById("div");
  div.style.width = width + "px";
}
```

```html
<style>
  #div {
    background: #0099CC;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: width 5s;
    -moz-transition: width 5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 5s;
  }
</style>
<div id="div"></div>
```